# Could not obtain identifier from

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am getting following problem when trying to save an Entity into `MongoDB` database.

I am using `Spring` `CrudRepository`

An my code looks as follow:

```
UserDocument user = processUser();
userRepository.save(user);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain identifier from UserDocument(id=null, ownerId=..., ...)!
    at o.s.d.m.TargetAwareIdentifierAccessor.getRequiredIdentifier(TargetAwareIdentifierAccessor.java:47)
    at o.s.d.m.c.EntityOperations$MappedEntity.getId(EntityOperations.java:466)
    ... 53 frames excluded
```

UserDocument class:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.CompoundIndex;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.CompoundIndexes;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@SuperBuilder
@Document(collection = UserDocument.COLLECTION)
public class UserDocument extends BaseDocument<ObjectId> {

  public static final String COLLECTION = "users";

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;

 .....
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the UserDocument has a definition requiring certain fields to make a key or id but those are not present. The solution may be to check those values are set on the UserDocument

Comment: Id is autogenerated, I will update question

Comment: Perhaps make sure you have a public getter/setter for your id, also possibly annotate it with  `@GeneratedValue(...)`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that is struggling with this problem - in my case it was problem with `mapstruct` `Mapper` that as a side effect was populating fields in super class:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Accessors(chain = true)
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class BaseDocument<ID extends Serializable> implements Persistable<ID> {

  @Version
  private Long revision;

  @CreatedDate
  private Instant createdDateTime;

  @LastModifiedDate
  private Instant lastModifiedDateTime;

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return isNull(createdDateTime);
  }
}
```

So make sure these fields are `null` when you are saving a new entity!

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this too. In my case, the problem was the `@Version` field in the object I was trying to save was set to 0. After I set it to null I didn't have this anymore.
I noticed the methods in the trace getQueryForVersion, doSaveVersioned...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain identifier from .....
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.TargetAwareIdentifierAccessor.getRequiredIdentifier(TargetAwareIdentifierAccessor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$MappedEntity.getId(EntityOperations.java:527)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$MappedEntity.getQueryForVersion(EntityOperations.java:556)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSaveVersioned(MongoTemplate.java:1383)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem most often occurs when you are using a Mongo database inside Spring application and you are trying to save (or overwrite) a document whose mandatory value is empty.

It is worth paying attention to the type of error that appears in the logs and check these top lines:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain identifier from XXX
at org.springframework.data.mapping.TargetAwareIdentifierAccessor.getRequiredIdentifier(TargetAwareIdentifierAccessor.java:48)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$MappedEntity.getId(EntityOperations.java:527)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$MappedEntity.getQueryForVersion(EntityOperations.java:556)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSaveVersioned(MongoTemplate.java:1383)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:1370)
```

The save method, instead of making a direct save to the database, makes an additional series of calls inside the spring mongo data library.

The **doSaveVersioned()** method catches our eye in particular. Inside this function, our service (unwittingly for us) tries to find an already existing record based on the ID to be able to verify and update the version. This of course causes an error, because such a document does not yet exist in the mongo database.

This app behavior is because one of your entities must have **@Version** annotation for one of the fields, for example:

```
public class YoursEntity {

   protected String id;

   protected String lastUpdateBy;

   protected Instant lastUpdateOn;

   protected String name;

   @Version
   protected Long version;
}
```

To fix this, you can do one of several things:

- get rid of the **@Version** annotation
- set the required field as null each time before saving

  ```
  yoursEntity.setId(null);
  yoursEntityRepo.save(yoursEntity);
  ```
- when passing data in the request body, do not include this field (e.g. in json) and add the following annotation above the class:

  ```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  public class YoursEntity {}
  ```